# Save file with different name from original (html)

Tags: html, save, filenames

I want to put a link on html which downloads a file with different filename from original. So for example there is this PNG file:

```
https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png
```

I would like to put it into html so that when you click to download it, it saves not as `"logo11w.png"` (which is the original name) but as another name, for example: `"Google Logo.png"`

I actually had saved the code to do this on my computer and now i have lost access to it and can't seem to find it on google, i tried several search queries. However, I remember it was a pretty short html code (1 line) however I just want to make this possible no matter if you guys give me another code, all that matters is that it works. Thanks!﻿

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced the same problem today and stumbled upon your question. Here's what I found:

```
<a href="url_to_logo11w.png" download="Google Logo.png">Download logo</a>
```

You can also achieve the same through javascript, here's the link:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_download.asp

Comment: thanks, this answer was really helpful, exactly what I needed!